# Sliding a ball on board

Tags: android, libgdx, box2d

to achieve pic 1 of [image]

what I was able to do was some what pic 2(with square body slanted so that ball is sliding down),with

```
public Body createCArea() {
        PolygonShape cShape = new PolygonShape();
        int value = 10;
        Vector2[] cVert = new Vector2[4];
        cVert[0] = new Vector2(90, 100);// -6,2
        cVert[1] = new Vector2(180, 55);// -2,6
        cVert[2] = new Vector2(-90, -100);// 2,6
        cVert[3] = new Vector2(-180, -55);//
        cShape.set(cVert);
        BodyDef standBodyDef = new BodyDef();
        standBodyDef.type = BodyType.StaticBody;
        standBodyDef.position.set(camera.viewportWidth * .55f, 170);
        FixtureDef standFixture = new FixtureDef();
        standFixture.shape = cShape;
        standFixture.density = 10;
        standFixture.friction = 0.3f;
        standFixture.restitution = 0f;

        Body standBody = world.createBody(standBodyDef);
        standBody.createFixture(createFixture(cShape));
        return standBody;
    }
```

and

```
public Body createBall()
    {
        BodyDef roundbody = new BodyDef();
        //  roundbody.position.set(new Vector2(0, 50));
            roundbody.type=BodyType.DynamicBody;
            roundbody.position.set(camera.viewportWidth * .60f, 260);
            Body rbody = world.createBody(roundbody);
            CircleShape dynamicCircle = new CircleShape();
            dynamicCircle.setRadius(15f);



            fixtureDef.shape = dynamicCircle;
            fixtureDef.density = 2f;
            fixtureDef.friction = 0.9f;
            fixtureDef.restitution = 0;
            rbody.createFixture(fixtureDef);
            return rbody;

    }
```

so what I should do to do pic 1,is it possible,new in box 2d

Comment: Are you trying to make it so that the ball still responds to gravity (falls downward) but does not collide with the box?

Comment: What I want to make is ball on the board coming down rotating over it(in contact with board and over it)

Comment: Objects "in contact" can't be on top of each other.  However, you could create the illusion of this by changing the collision bits when they first start colliding so that they are not colliding and then changing the effect of gravity on the ball.  When they are out of contact, change the collision bits again so that they can collide and set the gravity factor back to 1.0.  Is this kind of what you are looking for?

Comment: You can also achieve this effect, I think, by setting the ball as a sensor when it collides with the block and changing the gravity.  Then changing it back when the collision ends (BeginContact/EndContact).

Comment: Are you trying to model and/or render a 3D scene?

Comment: When you put box2d bodies on top of eachother like that, they tend to pop out and go flying off in random directions, so I would be inclined to agree with @FuzzyBunnySlippers.